# html5 framework to add events and animation easily

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

Is there an html5  js framework that adds events( eg click) to a animated elements in the canvas easily

or do you have to-do it old school by adding one click event to the canvas then work out by mouse coordinates if the click is in the correct location?

Below is a script that I wrote but its not working so well. Is there an easier way? Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body >

    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid red; position: absolute; top:0; left:0;">
            <p>Your browser doesn't support canvas.</p>
        </canvas>


</body>
</html>

<script type ="text/javascript">

    var context;
    var myRect = [];

    function Shape(x, y, w, h, fill) {
        this.speedX = 1;
        this.speedY = 1;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
        this.fill = fill;
    }

    // get canvas element.
    var elem = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

    // check if context exist
    if (elem.getContext) {

        context = elem.getContext('2d');



        myRect.push(new Shape(10, 0, 25, 25, "#333"))
        myRect.push(new Shape(0, 40, 39, 25, "#333"))
        myRect.push(new Shape(0, 80, 100, 25, "#333"))



    }

    function loop() {

        //console.log('tick');


        context.clearRect(0, 0, elem.width, elem.height);

        for (i in myRect) {

            //console.log(x);


            context.fillRect(myRect[i].x, myRect[i].y, myRect[i].w, myRect[i].h)

            myRect[i].x += myRect[i].speedX;

            //if (myRect[i].x >= elem.width - myRect[i]) {

            //}


            console.log(myRect[1].x  + '     '  +  myRect[1].y);

            //context.fillStyle = i.fill;
        }


        //context.clearRect(0, 0, elem.width, elem.height);
        //context = elem.getContext('2d');


    }

    setInterval(loop, 25);




    $('#myCanvas').click(function (evt) {

        var mouseX = evt.pageX;
        var mouseY = evt.pageY;

        //console.log('mouseX ' + mouseX + '     mouseY ' + mouseY);


        if (myRect[1].x < (mouseX + myRect[1].w) && myRect[1].x > mouseX && myRect[1].y < (mouseY + myRect[1].h) && myRect[1].y > mouseY) {
            alert('test');
        }



    });


</script>
```

Comment: do you want to share what you tried?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aqj_mVmuz3Y8dHNhUVFDYlRaaXlyX0xYSTVnalV5ZlE#gid=0

Comment: great thanks thats very interesting - fabric looks very cool

Comment: My best friend for this is [Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In no particular order, these canvas libraries are all good:

- [KineticJs](http://kineticjs.com/)
- [FabricJs](http://fabricjs.com/)
- [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/)
- [EaselJs](http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS)

Comment: Thanks what do you suggest is the easiest to start with.

Comment: In my opinion Kinetic and Raphael are the easiest to use. Personally I slightly prefer Kinetic but both are great.

Comment: thanks that's great - have you  tried collision testing - like the flash hitTest(). I've been reading online and it looks like I have to work out the coordinates of all the objects to so when they touch - do you know anything about this?